Can you tell if a Tile Shower Pan is Cracked without removing Tlies?
An Insurance Adjuster just declared my Tile Shower Pan “Cracked” without removing any surface Tiles. He based this on small cracks in some of the grout. How can he tell if the mud pan is cracked, and even if it were?… how would water get through the water barrier lining under the mud pan?
Additional Information
These are good questions, and I did not want to get verbose in my own question:
I live in Northern California.
It's a simple issue with a more complicated past.
At some point 13 years ago, the prior owner filed an insurance claim for a broken drain pipe in the upstairs master bath. This was on the Disclosure when we bought this house 10 years ago. I was an Insurance Agent for 5 years, after getting out of the Army, so I asked a prior fellow Agent to confirm this, and they did. The disclosure stated that the pipe was repaired, the tile floor was replaced, an extra cleanout was installed outside under the bathroom, and an access panel was installed outside to the subflooring. I confirmed all of this.
About 2 1/2 years ago, we had 27 new top-of-the-line thermal barrier windows installed. During this project, the Contractor asked about possible leaks or water damage in the ceiling, because during the prior owner's repair job, they had installed new drywall, and you can see the change and outline in texture.
There was also a small square of ceiling drywall cut out, because we had refinanced the house for equity and lower interest rates the year before, and the Home Inspector asked permission to cut and visually inspect. Nothing was found except the water stains from the prior disclosed claim that was repaired.
The Window Contractor questioned me further, and I mentioned that sometimes I could hear a light, rhythmic "thumping" sound in that wall. Since they warranty their windows and frames, he insisted that I bring in a plumber to check for leaks from the upstairs shower, which resides directly above the new drywall. I complied, and the plumber suggested that IF there was a leak, it might be from a cracked shower pan. He suggested that I should call my Insurance Company to have them determine if we needed to remove the tiles and inspect further.
I did so, and THIS is when an Adjuster came out to look. I relayed the information I had to him, and without any other evidence (other than the small cracks in tile grout I posted about), he declared it "Normal wear and tear, and a cracked shower pan"... then left and filed it that way.
I wanted my window project completed, and did not want to unnecessarily tear my bathroom floor out to get it done, so I hired two more plumbers to come investigate. Both determined that there was no leak (One did a "Cracked pan test" where you fill the shower basin up with 5 gallons of water, wait 10 minutes, then do it again if there is no leak and wait another 10 minutes... there was no leak). Both plumbers decided that what I was hearing was "Thermal expansion" in pipes and risers, and this satisfied my Window Contractor.
Now, 3 years later... We got hit with a massive storm, with winds gusting between 70 - 100mph on February 4th. We had 3 large Redwood Trees next to our house (16 tons each), two of them came down, partially striking our south wall and roof, and the third was still standing, but was observed swaying back and forth 30 degrees toward the house (7 feet from home), with the root ball surging 1 - 2 feet out of the ground, by fire crews and neighbors through the night (we were evacuated by the fire crew). It was declared a County-Wide Disaster, with a LOT of tree-related damage everywhere.
It's been a SLOW process getting Contractors out, due to very high demand, but our current Adjuster initially noted visible damage on the roof above the bathroom, a broken (shattered) bathroom window, two shattered solar panels, and EVERYTHING in our Back and Side Yards was smashed/destroyed by two of the massive trees when they came down, including an in-ground Pool Deck.
About 3 weeks after we returned home (we were evacuated for a week), we started noticing VERY high humidity in our Master Bath and attached Master Bedroom. The Insurance Company recommended bringing out "ServePro" to investigate. They recorded up to 99% humidity in the floor, wall, jacuzzi tub, and shower tiles... and recommended tearing it all out and doing remediation work, both upstairs and downstairs under the bathroom. THAT is when the Insurance Company pulled out the 2 1/2 year old "Denied Claim" for a cracked Shower Pan, and then sent out a Structural Engineer who used zero devices, did no testing, and declared that nothing in the Bathroom was related to the trees coming down (that broke the bathroom window, and damaged the roof...). Also, a roofer did finally make it out, and found a small hole above the master bath, and a "rust stain" from a nail in a ceiling stud has appeared right below that hole. This all seems pretty obvious to me, but I want outside objective opinions.
That is about as detailed as I can get here folks. My original question and request for opinions stands... Can ANYONE (not just an Insurance Adjuster) tell in a mud shower pan is "cracked and leaking" without pulling up tile and physically inspecting it?

Well, one possible answer is “experience”, but it’s also possible they’re wrong. Why are they there in the first place? Is there a known leak/damage that insurance is taking care of? Are they trying to avoid liability?

Far more information is needed here.  Why do you have an insurance adjuster looking at your shower pan?  What type of construction are  we talking about?  your location? What is your initial problem?  I find most adjusters have limited knowledge of building techniques, but there is too little here to make anything but a guess.
